# Загрузка *.txt через AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Нужно сделать загрузку txt-файла на сервер. До этого с загрузкой файлов не сталкивался ни разу. Делаю на основе разных статей на форумах. Вроде бы, всё ясно и понятно. Но у меня консоль выдаёт не то, что нужно. HTML структура вот такая:

```
<section class="uploadFile">
    <form action="getFile.php" method="post">
        <input type="file" name="file_txt" accept="text/plain">
        <input type="button" class="button" value="Загрузить файл">
    </form>
</section>
```

JavaScript (jQuery):

```
<script>
    jQuery('.uploadFile .button').click(function() {
        var file = jQuery('.uploadFile input[name=file_txt]').prop('files')[0],
            form_data = new FormData();
        form_data.append('file', file);
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: '/ajax/editProgram.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: form_data,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function(e) {
                var a = jQuery.parseJSON(e);
                console.clear();
                console.log(a);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

И принимающий PHP код:

```
<?php

$file = $_POST;

echo $file;

?>
```

Консоль выдаёт мне вот это:

```
(3) [null, "<a href="/2810-2810" target="_blank"></a>", ""]
```

Я не могу понять, что это за ответ такой? Откуда там взялась ссылка? Что это вообще за ссылка и куда делся тот файл, который я передавал?

У меня тестовый txt содержит список фильмов. Просто названия и всё. НИ ОДНОЙ ссылки в нём нет. Где ошибка?

Comment: `$file = $_POST['file'];`

Comment: Я изменил содержимое txt файла. Удалил всё и написал просто один символ "1". И всё равно мне выдаётся та ссылка...

Comment: Изменил на $_POST['file'] и всё равно результат тот же.

Comment: не понял, что вы хотите сделать, исходя из того, что в ответе вы ожидаете json, можете сделать примерно так в php **print json_encode($_FILES);**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$file = file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);

success: function(e) {
  console.clear();
  console.log(e);
}
```

Comment: Вернул тоже самое, только с экранированием.
[null,"<a href=\"\/2810-2810\" target=\"_blank\"><\/a>",""]

Comment: @LexXy У Вас на сервере выполняется неизмененный код.

Comment: Не понял. Это как?

Comment: @LexXy Не знаю. Например, не сохранили файл, сделав в нем изменения.

Comment: Всё сохранено...

Comment: Кстати, есть интересный момент. Я сейчас в PHP файле удалил содержимое. Файл абсолютно пустой. И всё равно в консоли выпадает то же сообщение.

Comment: @LexXy Значит, это вообще не тот php файл, который вызывается.`

Comment: @LexXy Хорошее определение - "интересный момент". Это ключевой момент!

Comment: Согласен. Была такая мысль. Я потом изменил название файла и JavaScript выдал ошибку. Т.е., файл тот, который нужен.

Answer (score -2):

Думаю форма должна содержать атрибут `enctype="multipart/form-data"`